# How to find out the font file path in Java 7 and 8

Tags: java, macos, swing, fonts, awt

In Java 7 and 8, as the `FontManager` has changed, so now I would to find out a font file path, for example `c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf`.  Now how can I do this with Java 7 and 8?

### Edit

I have a font object or the font name, now I would like to find out the font's file path. For example, I have got the font name or the `Font` object, such as `Extra CVS bold`, now I would like to have a way to get `c:/windows/fonts/x32cvs_b.ttf` where `x32cvs_b.ttf` is required.

Comment: *"In java 7 and 8, as the `FontManager` has changed,.."*  What on Earth is `FontManager`?  It is not in the [JSE 8 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html). Link to the Java Docs. Also *why* are you trying to get the path of the font?  What application feature does it serve?

Comment: @AndrewThompson it may look weird, but in mac the swing components don't render the utf-8 text data correctly, I found if I load the font directly from file/stream, the Java will render the text dat correctly. so this is the reason budy :)

Comment: Sounds like a [bug](http://bugs.java.com/) that would be better fixed than worked around..

Comment: And **what is `FontManager`**?

Comment: @AndrewThompson the `sun.font.FontManager` is a class which takes care about the installed fonts, load them and generally is a font context. This guy has some API changes after JDK7.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object font2D;
try {
    // Java 7+.
    font2D = Class.forName("sun.font.FontUtilities").getDeclaredMethod("getFont2D", new Class[] {Font.class})
        .invoke(null, new Object[] {font});
} catch (Throwable ignored) {
    font2D = Class.forName("sun.font.FontManager").getDeclaredMethod("getFont2D", new Class[] {Font.class})
        .invoke(null, new Object[] {font});
}
Field platNameField = Class.forName("sun.font.PhysicalFont").getDeclaredField("platName");
platNameField.setAccessible(true);
String file = (String)platNameField.get(font2D);
```